# How to find the linking path for extern variable

Tags: c++, linux

Is there any way to find the file/shared_object from where linking is happenning for an extern variable used in current file/module.

for example: In a large application sofware in linux, I want to find the declaration of a particular variable that I have externed in my module ...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not entirely sure to understand your question,  but perhaps [dladdr](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dladdr) should be suitable for your needs. `dladdr` is a Gnu/Glibc extension. From its manual:
*The function `dladdr()` takes a function pointer and tries to resolve name and file where it is located.* (and it very probably could be used with the pointer to a global variable).

However, I am puzzled by the phrasing of your question. The "declaration of a variable" has no sense inside executable ELF binaries or shared objects, because declaration is essentially a source code concept, not an object code one. And practically speaking, most declarations (of global variables) are inside some header file.

Be aware of [C++ name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)

If you have the source code of your application, you could use textual tools (like `grep` or `etags`) or even extend the GCC compiler thru plugins or [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extensions to find such declarations.

Of course, you can also use `dlsym` to find the address of some symbol, given its name.